# bug json on ajax request without error response status

Tags: ajax, json, special-characters, httpwebresponse

I sent a JSON string to my server to feed my database. But when my json contains the symbol &, I don't get any answer, not even an error response status.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: can you give an example of the json data being sent to your webserver...if you're sure you dont get a response or an error, are you sure the request is being made?

Comment: Some of your code would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your AJAX call is a GET method, you need to URLencode your parameters.

See String.encodeURIComponent()

Comment: So do I. If you just create some JSON and add it as a GET parameter you get exactly this.

Comment: no it's a post method. But i'll try with the get method using urlencode